# Availability calendar with time slots

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a booking system for my wordpress website where users have their own calendar where they can set available dates for appointments, and clients can see that calendar and choose from available dates and time slots to book an appointment.

So I need to code a calendar where time slots can be changed by the users and choosed by the clients but I'm having some problems with it.

The Idea was to make a Jquery calendar with time slots that clients can see. The users have their own managment page where they can choose available time slots and dates for that calendar, and it has to sync with appointments inside the mysql database so that the system can already make unavailable the dates associated to that appointment.

I already tryied looking for wordpress plugins but nothing has helped me. I also saw a similar question here but it's really outdated and doesn't have the answer I'm looking for. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: There are js libraries out there that do what you are looking for.  e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @Elvopresla That is why I'm asking what you want as to do. `I'm making` seems like you have started something then show us. `I'm having some problems` where is the problem? You didn't mention anywhere in your question that you only need a starting point.